# wordpress file upload permission error with 755

Tags: php, wordpress, file, file-upload, permissions

I've a problem with **wordpress file upload**, when I upload the file **wp** tell me that upload directory has no permission to write the folder or something like that. I faced that problem 1st of july when **wp** want to create a new directory into **/upload/2014/** folder. I just by-pass this problem using putty and make the folder manually by write a command, but didn't understand why the folders are not created into upload folder/directory. I checked the upload, 2014 directory folder permission using FTP I think they looks good, they are 755 permission.

When I want to create a folder into these directory by manually (using FTP), it blocked me and also told that permission denied. To know this issue I change their permissions using putty command. Last of all I got a that When **I set permission 777 or set the public permission to 7** to these folder, next I can create a file or folder into respective directory.

T think that tits bad practices to make the folder permission to **777**, by default the permission of file s **644** and folder iss **777**. And it should work, don't know why this is not working for me.

The wordpress site into AWS dedicated server. It may be hampers for server, I guess don't know exactly.

Can any one please help me to figure out this.

Thanks,
Biswajit Ghosh

Comment: can you provide exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @niravshah_php **Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/07**.
This functionality works fine in staging server, but didn't work in live (aws dedicated) server.

Comment: refer this link, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-38-image-upload-fails

Comment: Thanks my friend, it really worked!! Thanks once. :)

Comment: you're welcome friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-- START AMAZON INSTRUCTIONS --
To set file permissions

Add the www group to your instance.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo groupadd www
```

Add your user (in this case, ec2-user) to the www group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
```

Important - You need to log out and log back in to pick up the new group. You can use the exit command, or close the terminal window.

Log out and then log back in again, and verify your membership in the www group.

Log out.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ exit
```

Reconnect to your instance, and then run the following command to verify your membership in the www group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ groups
ec2-user wheel www
```

Change the group ownership of /var/www and its contents to the www group.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
```

Change the directory permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group write permissions and to set the group ID on future subdirectories.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
```

Recursively change the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group write permissions.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

-- END AMAZON INSTRUCTIONS --

Reference: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-38-image-upload-fails

Regards